# Медленный запрос.

Tags: c#, http, get

Есть код, которые через get-запрос дергает данные с сайта:

```
WebRequest reqGET = System.Net.WebRequest.Create( this.url_base[0]+this.realm_req+rname );
WebResponse resp = reqGET.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader( stream );
data = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Все бы ничего, да вот только работает он как-то странно. Может 15 минут пройти перед тем, как строка появиться. Можно ли ускорить эту "черепаху"? И правильно ли так get'ы отправлять?

Comment: Ну мало чего. Может у них защита от ботов:) Проверяют Ваш UserAgent и если он не тот, то отдают контент медленно. Либо просто Вы запрашиваете слишком много и часто, и сервер не справляется.

Написали бы хотя бы какой сервер.

Comment: Если бы я знал какой у них сервер. Вообще, делаю запрос к battle.net(то есть к wow armory). На питоне этот же запрос проходит за секунды. Ну не верю я в то, что скриптовый язык может быть быстрее компилируемого.

Comment: Во первых иногда - действительно может, грань сейчас довольно тонкая, но 15 минут это действительно через-чур...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробовал запрашивать страницу battle.net много раз на примере [Создание web-запроса и получение ответа](http://kbyte.ru/ru/Programming/Sources.aspx?id=972&mode=show), все прошло успешно и без серьезных задержек.

Comment: Ну eu.battle.net это не eu.battle.net/api/wow. С первым проблем действительно нет, а вот со вторым начинаются. Правда недавно опять взялся за код и немного удивился: время ответа сервера упало до 30-40 секунд, но это все так же не приемлемо для меня(оно колеблется от 2 до, в среднем, 40 секунд). В чем причина до сих пор не помойму.